# iOS NSURLConnection delegate issue

Tags: ios, delegates, nsurlconnection

I have a view which has a UITableView where I am lazy loading images.  I have a class called ThumbDownloader where I initialize an NSURLConnection and upon finishing loading the image when connectionDidFinishLoading is called, within connectionDidFinishLoading, I make a call like this back to my main view:

```
[delegate appImageDidLoad:self.indexPathInTableView];
```

In my main view I have an array of ThumbDownloader instances.  The array is named:  imageDownloadsInProgress

The problem is, if I enter the view and quickly exit it before all of the images are done downloading, I get the zombie:

```
 -[myApp appImageDidLoad:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xa499030
```

I have tried a bunch of ways to release the ThumbDownloader instances in dealloc and such, but nothing seems to work.

Here is where I set up the instance and add it to the array:

```
- (void)startIconDownload:(Product *)product forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ThumbDownloader *thumbDownloader = [imageDownloadsInProgress objectForKey:indexPath];
    if (thumbDownloader == nil) 
    {
        thumbDownloader = [[ThumbDownloader alloc] init];
        thumbDownloader.product = product;
        thumbDownloader.imageSizeWidth = 87;
        thumbDownloader.imageSizeHeight = 87;
        thumbDownloader.indexPathInTableView = indexPath;
        thumbDownloader.delegate = self;
        [imageDownloadsInProgress setObject:thumbDownloader forKey:indexPath];
        [thumbDownloader startDownload];
        [thumbDownloader release];   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you clear the delegate on the NSURLConnection.

Comment: ...and make sure to call cancel on the connection

Comment: how do i go about doing this?

Comment: [connection setDelegate:nil];

Comment: there is no such method setDelegate.  Maybe an iOS6 thing?

Comment: okay in ThumbDownloader dealloc, I put self setDelegate:nil and this does make sense...and I put a breakpoint and it does hit it several times but the end result is still the same error

Comment: Sorry, my bad, yes, you should be clearing the thumbdownloader's delegate (not the NSURLConnection).  Anyways, the problem seems to be that your thumbdownloaders are not getting dealloc'd before your mainview (that contains the table view).  It's not clear from the code where the release of the thumbdownloaders occurs...

Comment: Yes this is why I was trying to loop through 'imageDownloadsInProgress' and release all the ThumbDownloaders before releasing my main view, but I couldnt find a good way to do that.

Comment: I think you may need to move the NSURLConnection "cancel" out of the thumb dealloc.  The reason (I think) is that NSURLConnection does a retain on it's delegate so your dealloc won't get called until the connection is done.

Comment: hmm tried that and nothing...this is crazy, probably something really simple just overlooking

Comment: in your mainview's (with the table) dealloc, you should loop thru the imageDownloadsInProgress and for each ThumbDownloader call cancel on the connection and setDelegate:nil.  Then release the imageDownloadsInProgress.  At that point, the thumbdownloads deallocs should all get called.  if not, you might NSLog what the retainCount on each thumbdownload is (while looping thru the list).  It should be no more than 2 I'd think....

Comment: I have tried multiple ways to do exactly that and when I do I get this: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSIndexPath setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: that would indicate the ThumbDownloader in the array has already been released or you're calling setDelegate on the wrong object.

Comment: In the case of cancelling the download, I get this error:  NSIndexPath cancelDownload: and I am first checking if the instance of thumbDownload == nil, wish i could post the code here..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17420/discussion-between-boostedz06-and-mike-m)

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
[connection cancel]
```

in the dealloc method of ThumbDownloader class. This will cancel the ongoing download and will prevent the message from being called.

Comment: I already call connection cancel and connection release in my dealloc in ThumbDownloader.  The problem is, I feel like I need to release thumbdownloader itself.

Comment: i've assumed that you are calling [imageDownloadsInProgress release] in the viewDidUnload method.

Comment: well, i am calling [imageDownloadsInProgress release] in dealloc of my main view.  isn't viewDidUnload deprecated now?  I am using ios6